Problems recognizing a single number with google-text-to-speech
I am working on a Speech-to-Text recognition for an application that asks questions whose answer needs to be a number.
I am having problems trying to recognize just one number with Google text-to-speech. For example, if I say "one" the transcription returned will be empty (like it is considered background noise but detected something), but If I say something else after that for example "one" again the transcription will return "one" "one". This is happening for the numbers from 1 to 10 and short words.
This is the code:
startListening() {

                  const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
               
                  const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

                  recognition.lang = "en-US";
                  recognition.interimResults = true;
                  recognition.continuous = true;

                  recognition.onstart = () => {
                    console.log("Start...");
                    this.isRecording = true;
                  }

                  recognition.onend = () => {
                      console.log('end')
                      this.isRecording = false;
                  }

                 recognition.onresult = (event) => {
                    console.log("Result:", event.results[event.results.length - 1][0].transcript)
                 }

                 recognition.start()

             }

I want the code to recognize the number the first time so it is not necessary to say something else after the number.

Did you try it with FLAC (or whatever that other one is, linear?)

Yes, but that doesn't solve this issue
